# How to create a page category of products in Commerce 2?

Tags: 8, commerce

Usually in commerce 1 did:
Display-products (node), in which field "Catalog" of taxonomy-term.
Create a displays. Go to the term page and see all products! Great!

In commerce 2 tried to do but failed, probably because product is not a node, and the view for taxonomy, only works on him and no teaser.

Tell me, how do organized easy catalog on commerce2?

Preferably without the panels and search_api. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/276163/7177 should've been marked as a duplicate for this but it already has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is an issue with Drupal core itself and the Views module.

As you mentioned right now the taxonomy term views in core has `Content: has taxonomy term ID` which only work with nodes.

It should be `Entity: has taxonomy term ID` so it can handle other entities such as Drupal Commerce products

There's an issue in [Drupal core/views here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2915933) that you can read about it, for the time being there's a module that will help you out with this situation.

**[Commerce: Product taxonomy filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/product_taxonomy_filter)**

> The Module extends Taxonomy module from Drupal core and provides a new
>   contextual filter "Product has taxonomy term ID (with depth)".

*Note that the contexual filter has to know your entity reference machine name*