# Taxonomy Terms Not Displaying Results

Tags: 8, commerce, taxonomy-terms

I have added product categories vocabulary to my default product type. Added few products through that default product type and selected relevant terms for each product I added.

When I am going to term page it is not displaying the products associated with that term.

Are there any additional steps required for that?

Comment: Pls check your Teaser view mode for your product type/variant

Comment: For Product Variation Types I have only Default, Cart & Summary, May I add new view mode for teaser.

Comment: yes, as I know taxonomy term page shows all related content with Teaser view mode

Comment: I did that but no luck. Now removing taxonomy term filed from product type and adding that to product variation type. Let's see if that make it work

Comment: I created the issue on Drupal Commerce and find out that

"the default taxonomy term listing only supports nodes"
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2988132

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a page category of products in Commerce 2?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238589/how-to-create-a-page-category-of-products-in-commerce-2)